# stack children is overflowing on image

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I clip to hardedge in stack even after this black container is overflowing how can i fix this if i do fit: BoxFit.fill the image get stretched. i tried wrapping the stack in a container or card and then clip to haredge that didnt work too

here is the code i tried

```
 Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(widget.image), fit: BoxFit.fill),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: 43,
            width: 162,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.35),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
             ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(widget.info,style: RecentChats.likedetails,),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 4,
                          width: 4,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: DatingColoCodes.blue,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(widget.view,style: RecentChats.viewprofile,),
                ],
              )),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, but is the image also 162px wide? Because you defined the black container to be a fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce with the given snippet, it works just fine on me when I run it, maybe try to put the complete snippet?

But anyways, you can achieve the same behavior without the `Stack` widget, just put the `Text`s as a child of the `Container` whose hold the image.

Here is the working example, you can copy paste and [run in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter?null_safety=true)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 8,
          childAspectRatio: 0.8,
          children: [
            for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
              Container(
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage('https://source.unsplash.com/random'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                /// For some reason, GridView / Container are stretching
                /// the height, forcing it to be in full height so we gotta
                /// do some hack, we put a Column, and then put the Container
                /// with the texts inside the Column as well and make the height
                /// as height as the item height by using `MainAxisSize.min`.
                ///
                /// The first Column is to position the Container inside it to
                /// the bottom of the item (see: `MainAxisAlignment.end`) and force
                /// the width to be full width by using `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`
                ///
                /// Lastly, we do a `Clip.hardEdge` to prevent the text container
                /// to apear sharp-squared and follow the roundness of the parent
                /// container instead.
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.70),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Text('Hello item $i'),
                          Text('Washington DC'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sidenote: when I say "*forcing it to be full height*", it means adding height property will simply just not work, that is why I put a column instead.